# rails routing controller action change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm struggling here with a problem:
I have a controller *questions* which has action *new*.
Whenever I need to create new question, I'm typing

```
/questions/new
```

What changes to routes.rb should I make to change the URI to

```
/questions/ask
```

---

Thank you.
Valve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
map.ask_question   '/questions/ask', :controller => 'questions', :action => 'new'
```

Then you'll have a named route and you can:

```
link_to "Ask a question", ask_question_path
```

Comment: Hi, Christian.
Will this enable me to type http://mySite/questions/ask and go to
ask controller? Please note that I'm trying to use RESTful routing.
Thanks,
Valve.

Comment: Christian's solution points http://mySite/questions/ask to the new action in the QuestionsController, which will (by default) render app/views/questions/new.html.erb.  It does _NOT_ stop users from going to /questions/new to achieve the same result.

Comment: @Valve it will go to the questions controller with action new. It is RESTful indeed as you're using both the URL and request type.

@Gaius you're right. To prevent users from going to /questions/new you have to remove the default route at the end of the routes.rb file.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using RESTful routes maybe you'd like to use map.resources for your *questions*.

To rename the action urls you may do this:

`map.resources :questions, :path_names => { :new => 'ask', :delete => 'withdraw' }`

(I added delete for the sake of the example)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of rails?

Generally the default route should catch anything like /:controller/:action, so you could just create an ask method in your questions controller. Take a look at the api documentation for named_route and map_resource if you want something a bit smoother to work with.

Comment: Hello, Jason. Rails 2.2.2.
I try to use RESTful routing, so I deleted the default two routes 
(controller/action/id and the other).
I'd expect something like
map.resources :questions, :action=>{:new=>:ask}
if it is possible.
Thanks.